# good parser for key=value CRLF file

Tags: javascript

Any sample code how to make hashmap or similar list from

```
key=value CRLF   
key2=value2 CRLF
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `CR`, `LF`, and `=` are all protected characters (i.e., they cannot occur in `key` or `value`), you could simply do:

```
var str = "key=value\r\nkey2=value2\r\n";
var lines = str.split("\r\n");
var map = {};
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var pieces = lines[i].split("=");
  if (pieces.length == 2)
    map[pieces[0]] = pieces[1];
}
```

Comment: This will add a bogus key ''->undefined, due to the trailing CRLF. Best put a check that lines[i] is not blank (or maybe that it contains '=') before splitting and adding.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var str = "key=value\r\nkey2=value2\r\n";

var re = /([^=]*)=(.*?)\r\n/g, match, map = { };

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  map[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://krook.org/jsdom/
see the String.split method.
split first on crlf (\r\n I believe) and then split on "="